# sharepoint Javascript The collection has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Hi i tried to make the tutorial on MSDN. Here is the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx And here is my Java Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scriptbase = "https://example.at/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", doNext());
    });
});
var siteUrl = "/knowledge/lzpowerbase";
function doNext() {
    console.log("SharePoint geladen!!");
    retrieveListItems(siteUrl);
}
function retrieveListItems(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Component Documents');    
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);    
    clientContext.load(collListItem);    
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));                
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();        
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
            '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
            '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
    }
    alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```

Every time i try to run it it says: Error: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

And i have no clue why. I tried to google it but didnt found anything becouse i dont was specific stuff i want everything in the list so i can access and use it. Any Help would be great. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example the specified error occurs due to the line:

```
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", doNext());
```

Due to invalid invocation of `doNext` function, `collListItem` object is not getting initialized in that case.

**Solution**

Since [`jQuery.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) accepts *callback function* as a second argument, replace the line:

```
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", doNext());
```

with:

```
$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", doNext);
```

Comment: If above solution doesnt work, replace collListItem in success function with this.collListItem